# Spawned asteroid move towards player location found on spawn, but goes no farther

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating an Asteroids clone for a project. I currently am using MoveTowards to have the asteroids move where the player was once they spawned. What's limiting me using this method is they pause once they reach that point, which I know is due to MoveTowards. Is there another method for having the asteroid track the player location once it spawns and then moving to and BEYOND that point? Was trying to search around and couldn't find a specific answer to my question

Here is what I currently have that's applicable to this question. If I need to supply any more code please let me know and I will.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Asteroids : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector3 playerPosition;
    public Vector2 direction;
    public int asteroidSpeed;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        playerPosition = GameManager.gm.player.transform.position;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, playerPosition, asteroidSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want your vector to be BASED ON the line described by the initial point and the spawn point.  Then, you want to move along that vector, but NOT move "to" the spawn point.

Comment: I understand the idea but how would I go about actually writing that? Sorry I'm still learning.

Comment: Ah I got it! Came back to it after a break and this explanation made a lot more sense. Thank you :)